# Problem with adding up two numbers from a list. Python

Tags: python, list, numbers, combinations, addition

I'm really new to programming (two days old), so excuse my python dumbness. I've recently run into a problem with adding up to numbers from a list. I've managed to come up with this program:

```
list_nums = ["17", "3"]           
num1 = list_nums[0]                            
num2 = list_nums[1]                      
sum = (num1) + (num2)                        
print(sum)
```

the problem is that instead of adding up num1 with num2 (17+3=20), Python combines both numbers (i.e. "173"). what can I do in order to add up the numbers, instead of combining them?

Comment: They are strings. Try: `sum = int(num1) + int(num2)`, or use `list_nums = [17, 3] `

Comment: @GAEfan Putting parentheses around a single value does not make a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

`"17"` and `"3"`These are string, if you remove double-quotes from them, they become integers `17` and `3`.

So if you want to add 2 numbers, they have to be `integer` or `float` in Python.

Just remove double-quotes in list:
`list_nums = [17, 3]`

Answer (score 0):

Your `num1` and `num2` variables contain string values `'17'` and `'3'`. Operator `+` for strings works as a concatenation, e.g. `'17' + '3' == '173'`. If you need to get 20 out of it, you need to work with numeric types, like integers. For that, you either need to remove quotes from your 17 and 3 literals:

```
list_nums = [17, 3]           
num1 = list_nums[0]                            
num2 = list_nums[1]                      
acc = num1 + num2
print(acc)
```

...or convert strings to integers on the fly:

```
list_nums = ["17", "3"]           
num1 = list_nums[0]                            
num2 = list_nums[1]                      
acc = int(num1) + int(num2)
print(acc)
```

**P.S.** `sum` is the name of a built-in function in python. It's in general a good idea to avoid overriding such names. Other common names to avoid: `id`, `type`, `min`, `max`, etc.

Comment: problem was already solved, but this is some very useful information I will most certainly use in the future. thank you.